# Integer Not Adding PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I've got a function on my website so that when people click on a link, they are supposed to have 5 points added to their profile, but that doesn't seem to be working, instead their points just stick to 5.

The following code is what I have used to set up a function:

```
$points = $user_data['points'];

function pointAdd($user_id, $points) {
$user_id = (int)$user_id;
$pointsPlus = $points += 5;

mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `points` = '$pointsPlus' WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
}
```

And I have added this to the page, so that when they enter it, the code is put into play:

```
$target = $_GET['target'];


if(logged_in() === true){
    pointAdd($session_user_id, $pointsPlus);
    header('Location: ' . $target);
    exit();
}
```

But, when they enter the page, the function doesn't work and the user is just set to 5 points instead of having 5 extra added to their profile.

Comment: In the following line `pointAdd($session_user_id, $pointsPlus);` where does `$pointsPlus` come from? That is the name of the variable you create inside your function - outside the function there is `$points` - perhaps that is the parameter you need to add to your function call?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks

Comment: didn't work @RamRaider

Comment: Which data you pass in this $pointsPlus  variable??

Comment: Can you please re word? @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Comment: You need to do a check to see what their current points in the db are and then add on to that. All I see is an UPDATE where all you are doing is giving the user 5 points which gets rid of the value already in the DB. So do a SELECT in db first grab their current points then add on to that and UPDATE. I think I am confusing myself so I hope I don't confuse you.

Comment: Haha, yes, I'm a bit confused... Maybe if you just show me as an answer? I'll give you a tick if it works! @JoshuaNightingale

Comment: Didn't work? @Martin Joó did exactly what I suggested and it worked! ;-)

Comment: I thought you meant change `$pointsPlus` to just `$points` hah @RamRaider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pointsPlus variable that you pass into your function is empty. I don't know where user_data comes from, but the solution is something like this. And also the name 'pointsPlus' is logically incorrect, because there are the base points that the user already has.

```
$target = $_GET['target'];

if(logged_in() === true){
    $points = $user_data['points'];
    pointAdd($session_user_id, $points);
    header('Location: ' . $target);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thankyou! This is what I was looking for! You sir, have earn't yourself a tick :) what would you recommend instead of pointsplus?